# Ngrx Testing selector with jasmine marbles: Expected $.length = 1 to equal 2

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ngrx, jasmine-marbles

I am trying to test a simple loader component which is getting its state from an ngrx selector I have made. The selector is providing an object (interface name is LoaderState) `{queue: number}` which I map in a boolean value to show or hide the loader.

In order to test it I am utilising jasmine marbles and mockStore from ngrx.  I am overriding the selector, I am creating an expected cold observable with the expected value and then I use expect to be observale.

I have followed the tutorials in the [ngrx doc](https://next.ngrx.io/guide/store/testing) and from [Angular Up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jh3uEy6dcVo) conf.

### The component

```
export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {
  state: Observable<boolean>

  constructor(
    private store: Store<State>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.state = this.store.select(selectLoader).pipe(
      map(state => !!state.queue)
    )
  }

}
```

### The spec

```
describe('LoaderComponent', () => {
  let component: LoaderComponent
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoaderComponent>
  let store: MockStore<State>
  let loaderSelector: MemoizedSelector<State, LoaderState>

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoaderComponent ],
      providers: [ provideMockStore()]
    }).compileComponents()
    store = TestBed.get(Store)
    loaderSelector = store.overrideSelector(selectLoader, {queue: 0})
  }))

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoaderComponent)
    component = fixture.componentInstance
    fixture.detectChanges()
  })

  it('should hidden', () => {
    const expected = cold('(a|)', { a: false })
    expect(component.state).toBeObservable(expected)
  })
})
```

I expect the test to pass and also the code runs without a problem, but the test is failing and the resulted errors are:

```
[ { frame: 0,
        notification: { kind: 'N', value: false, error: undefined, hasValue: true } ‍},‍
‍      { frame: 0,‍
‍        notification: { kind: 'C', value: undefined, error: undefined, hasValue: false } ‍} ]
     
    Expected $.length = 1 to equal 2. 
    Expected $[1] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 0, notification: Notification({ kind: 'C', value: undefined, error: undefined, hasValue: false }) }).
```

Comment: Try after removing | from ‘cold’ first parameter. After removing of | it should work.

Comment: @user2216584 thank you very much, indeed it is working. I can not completely understand why the | is the problem, as it is normal for the observable to complete. If you could shed some light, it would be even more helpful. Thanks again

Comment: In marbles diagram ‘|’ represents the completion event. In your case component.state observable will never compete because store selectors are basically BehaviorSubject which behaves like a never complete observable until the usage of that selector’s pipeline does not have any way to complete the final observable. If you use take(1) operator in your component.state observable pipeline then having | in cold will pass the test. Hope it helps.

Comment: @user2216584 it makes total sense. Super thanks for the info and the answer.